# Can't find settings for restricted profiles

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, restricted-profiles

I have a new Asus Memo Pad 7 with Android 4.3 installed and I want to add a restricted profile, though I can't find the menu to do it. On the [Google Support page](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/3175031?hl=en) it says it's located in `Settings > Users > Add user or profile` but I don't even have a `Users` section in the settings app.

What am I missing?

---

The reason I want restricted profile is that I want to restrict the tablet to a single app and require a password to exit the app and after some searching it seems like restricted profile does just that, right?

Answer (score 1):

I presume that you have root and got a terminal emulator installed. These are the steps you need to do:

1. `Su`
2. `pm get-max-users`
3. `setprop fw.max_users 8`

Now the `users` section should be visible, if it isn't make a user account like this:

`pm create-user user_name`

Hope my answer helped.

Comment: I have not done anything to the tablet, I'm new to Android and thought this setting was standard

Comment: It is but it is official released in android 5.0+ so if you have KitKat or below you will need root :-(

Comment: Unfortuanally there is no other way :-(